# How can I make all the elements inside the page without being cut in any screen resolution?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I have three elements on my page, which are pictures, Card(containing picture and several typography), a Button. The direction is column.

The problem is the pictures and the button will be cut due to the screen resolution. How can I make those three elements inside the page without being cut?

This is what I expect:
[image]

The problem, the pictures and the button will be cut.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<Box
  sx={{
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    overflow: 'auto',
  }}
> 

  <Grid
    container
    direction="column"
    alignItems="center"
  >
    <Grid item>
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        image="logo.png"
        alt="logo"
        sx={{
          width: { xs: '80%', sm: '100%', md: '100%', lg: '100%', xl: '100%' }
        }}
        style={{ margin: '0 auto' }}
      />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>

  <Grid container direction="row" justifyContent="center">
    <Grid item xs={9} sm={8.6} md={6} lg={5} xl={4}>
      <Card 
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderRadius: '4px'
        }}
      >
        <Box
          sx={{mt:4, mb:4, mx:4}}
        >
          <Box>
            <Stack 
              direction={{xs: "column", sm: "row"}}
              alignItems={{xs: "center", sm: "flex-start"}}
              justifyContent={{xs: "center", sm: "flex-start"}}
              spacing={{ xs: 0, sm: 3}}
            >
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                sx={{ width: {xs: 120, sm: 160}, height: {xs: 120, sm: 160} }}
                image="image.png"
                alt="image"
                style={{borderRadius: "6px"}}
              />
              <Box
                sx={{wordWrap: "break-word", overflow: "hidden"}}
              >
                <Typography>
                  .....
                </Typography>
                <Typography>
                  .....
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            </Stack>
          </Box>
        </Box>
        <Box
          sx={{mx:4, mb: 10, wordWrap: "break-word", overflow: "hidden"}}
        >
          <Box>
            <Typography>
              .....
            </Typography>
            <Typography>
              .....
            </Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box
            sx={{mt:2}}
          >
            <Typography>
              .....
            </Typography>
            <Typography>
              .....
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Card> 
    </Grid>
  </Grid>

  <Grid container direction="row" justifyContent="center">
    <Grid item xs={9} sm={8.6} md={6} lg={5} xl={4}>
      <Button 
        onClick={() => setStep(2)}
      >
        Next
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Box>
```

Comment: not much into css but you could try to set height and width to auto in <Box> component and remove margin 0 auto from all other parts and keep that margin 0 auto in Box itself

Answer (score -1):

Try to add some padding to container element.

Comment: I have tried it, but it still can't solve it. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).